PROBLEM WITH USING STEAM, AMD GPU
I just installed 24.04 and i want to try steam in linux. As you can see below my hardware is old but i think i miss something because when i try to run steam it tries to initiate but it fails i only see the tray button, also i get some log errors. I want just casual gaming (eg eu4 game of 2013, 4gb storage and without big demands in terms of gpu) but my main problem is that i cant figure out how to see which video card uses and also where to search to fix the problem, is it because 24.04 is new and i have to wait for updates, is it because this gpu isnt compatible with ubuntu? I had dual boot and it worked fine with windows, i just reinstalled so i can merge working and gaming in one os. Even roasting will be appreciated as long as you can navigate where to search for solution, thanks beforehand and i hope i am in right section
log errors:
14:38:16 tee: steamwebhelper.sh[21431]: Starting steamwebhelper under bootstrap sniper steam runtime at /home/kotsosthegreatreloaded/.steam/debian-installation/ubuntu12_64/steam-runtime-sniper
14:38:10 steam: RegisterForAppOverview 2: 6ms
14:38:06 tee: steamwebhelper.sh[21147]: Starting steamwebhelper under bootstrap sniper steam runtime at /home/kotsosthegreatreloaded/.steam/debian-installation/ubuntu12_64/steam-runtime-sniper
14:38:03 steam: RegisterForAppOverview 2: 11ms
14:37:59 vulkandriverque: MESA-INTEL: warning: Haswell Vulkan support is incomplete
14:37:57 steam-runtime-l: bus_name=com.steampowered.PressureVessel.LaunchAlongsideSteam
14:37:57 steam: Steam Runtime Launch Service: steam-runtime-launcher-service is running pid 20805
14:37:56 tee: steamwebhelper.sh[20702]: Starting steamwebhelper under bootstrap sniper steam runtime at /home/kotsosthegreatreloaded/.steam/debian-installation/ubuntu12_64/steam-runtime-sniper
14:37:55 steam: /usr/share/themes/Yaru-viridian-dark/gtk-2.0/hacks.rc:28: error: invalid string constant "normal_entry", expected valid string constant
14:37:53 bash: steam.sh[20482]: Steam client's requirements are satisfied
14:37:53 setup.sh: setup.sh[20553]: Steam runtime environment up-to-date!
14:37:53 bash: steam.sh[20482]: STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
14:37:53 systemd: Started app-gnome-steam-20482.scope - Application launched by gnome-shell.
14:37:51 gnome-shell: g_closure_unref: assertion 'closure->ref_count > 0' failed

System Details Report
Report details

Date generated:                              2024-05-06 14:33:54

Hardware Information:

Hardware Model:                              Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd. B85M-HD3
Memory:                                      16.0 GiB
Processor:                                   Intel® Core™ i5-4460  × 4
Graphics:                                    OLAND
Graphics 1:                                  Intel® HD Graphics 4600 (HSW GT2)
Disk Capacity:                               3.0 TB

Software Information:

Firmware Version:                            F1
OS Name:                                     Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
OS Build:                                    (null)
OS Type:                                     64-bit
GNOME Version:                               46
Windowing System:                            Wayland
Kernel Version:                              Linux 6.8.0-31-generic

lshw -c video:
      *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Oland PRO [Radeon R7 240/340 / Radeon 520]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
       configuration: depth=32 driver=radeon latency=0 resolution=1920,1080
       resources: irq:39 memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f7e00000-f7e3ffff ioport:e000(size=256) memory:c0000-dffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 06
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:38 memory:f7800000-f7bfffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff


Start steam in a terminal to see more errros. Try xorg instead of Wayland. Flip the "Use default gpu" setting in steam settings.  Search this site for "steam use default gpu' and see problems others have had. Add info to your original posting instead of in the comments.

What ubfan is trying to tell you is that Steam is trying to start using your Discrete GPU instead of your Integrated GPU  You need to tell steam to use device with Physical ID 2 instead of Physical ID 0
